# Mysql server not starting

Tags: rhel, mysql

I installed Mysql server 5.7.9 on RHEL 6.5 using mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm Repo. And installation was successfull but when i try to start it up and gives errors. And from /var/log/mysqld.log i get these logs

```
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.473839Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support
> available 2016-02-16T08:16:55.473945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and
> rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 2016-02-16T08:16:55.473983Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 2016-02-16T08:16:55.474011Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.474038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use
> zlib 1.2.3 2016-02-16T08:16:55.474062Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux
> native AIO 2016-02-16T08:16:55.474908Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of
> pools: 1 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475257Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU
> crc32 instructions mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibUFqzVe'
> (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475430Z 0
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475460Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization
> aborted with error Generic error 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475490Z 0 [ERROR]
> Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475515Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as
> a STORAGE ENGINE failed. 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475536Z 0 [ERROR] Failed
> to initialize plugins. 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475557Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475583Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.475695Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin
> 'keyring_file' 2016-02-16T08:16:55.476442Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld:
> Shutdown complete
> 
> 2016-02-16T08:16:55.502968Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Any advice what this error is talking about ......

Comment: And what do you think the problem is?

Comment: "RHEL 6.5 using mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm" ... read it twice (or more) and try to find the first problem :)

Comment: Oh it was typo error actually it is mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL server is not able to access your /tmp directory, to write and create temporary files. Make sure /tmp directory is owned by root user and sticky bit is set on /tmp directory. Type the following commands to fix this error. You must be login as root user and type:

## chown root:root /tmp

## chmod 1777 /tmp

### test it

## /etc/init.d/mysqld start

Comment: Yes dear directory was available to root but sticky bit was not set and after setting sticky bit im able to start the service ......

Comment: changing system dir permissions is the worst idea ever :) And if /tmp is set badly, it means the system is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
```

This line looks like a problem there. Try to check if `/tmp` dir exists (it should) and is available for mysql user (or the user you use). You can try to use a different path with `--tmpdir` or an option within config, more info [at docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html)).

There can be problem with SELinux too (if it is in Enforcing mode). Check your audit log (eg. with `ausearch -ts today -m avc | audit2allow`) if /tmp dir isn't blocked for mysql. For tests you can disable SELinux with `setenforce 0`.

Comment: ausearch is for people who have auditing enabled, right?

Comment: sure, ausearch is effective only when your selinux is in enforcing or permissive mode.